# How to delete a taxonomy term with a broken URL

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I was trying to change the URL pointed to by a taxonomy term so that clicking on it would take the user to a map. However, after changing the URL I am no longer able to go into the term to edit the value. 
How can I switch the URL back, or delete the term altogether when I can't access it's edit screen?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I was able to open up the database and view the url_alias table.

From there I simply changed the url back to the automatically generated url that I overwrote.